# Working (real) voltage offset of isolated DC/DC modules

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, isolated

I do not see in 95% maybe cases for isolated DC/DC modules such a parameter like "Maximum-rated isolation working voltage" but see something like "I/O isolation 5000 VAC rated for 250VAC working voltage" or "Input To Output (60sec)". How to understand real possible working voltage offset between input and output (working, long time)? For example, the output should be shifted on -1000Vdc.